# Adjusting Y-ticks in stacked bargraph

Tags: r

My question here is how can I change the intervals of Y-axis ticks from 0.2 to 0.1? I've tried everything but I am very stuck! Picture of stacked-bargraph at bottom of post

```
dpi=600    #pixels per square inch

A <- c(0.417, 0.583, 0.0)
B <- c(0.7143, 0.2857, 0.0)
C <- c(0.3571, 0.4286, 0.2143)
D <- c(0.2593, 0.6297, 0.111)
data <- c(A, B, C, D)

X <- matrix(data, ncol= 4, nrow=3) 
print(X)


tiff("output.tif", width=6*dpi, height=5*dpi, res=dpi)

barplot(as.matrix(X)) 
cols <- c("#999999", "#00FF00", "#FF0000")
barplot(X, col=cols, main="Association Pollution", 
        sub="Safer® Brand Natural Fungicide", xlab="Concentration",
        ylab="Ratio of Response", ytick<-seq(0.0, 1, by=0.1), las=1, 
        names=c('Control', '0.1 μL', '1 μL', '10 μL'), xlim=c(0,6))
legend("topright", inset=c(0.01, 0.01), cex=0.55, 
       c("No Response", "Correct", "Incorrect"), fill=c("#999999", "#33FF33", "#FF0000"))

dev.off()
```

[image: my bargraph]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make use of the formatting tools in question editor, this time I've helped you. You will be able to post images if you have enough reputation, in the meantime others are willing to unlock them for you (unless you post code in images).

Answer (score 2):

You were close, there's no `yticks` argument in `barplot()`, it's actually `yaxp`<sup>1</sup>. Also we use `=` for function arguments and `<-` for assignment outside of functions.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Credits actually to *@rawr*</sup>

You won't need a sequence, since `yaxp=c(0, 1, 10)` means "from 0 to 1: make 10 breaks".

```
tiff("output.tif", width=6*dpi, height=5*dpi, res=dpi)

cols <- c("#999999", "#00FF00", "#FF0000")
barplot(X, col=cols, main="Association Pollution",
        sub="Safer® Brand Natural Fungicide", xlab="Concentration",
        ylab="Ratio of Response", yaxp=c(0, 1, 10), las=1, 
        names=c('Control', '0.1 μL', '1 μL', '10 μL'), xlim=c(0, 6))
legend("topright", inset=c(0.01, 0.01), cex=0.55, 
       c("No Response", "Correct", "Incorrect"), fill=c("#999999", "#33FF33", "#FF0000"))

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: you can just do `barplot(X, yaxp = c(0, 1, 10), las = 1)`, too

Comment: @rawr Thanks a ton, didn't know that before! The features of `barplot` really seem endless, I keep learning new things!